# Flutter textFormfield is not coming in center

Tags: flutter

I need to center the Textformfield widget i ahve wrapped in column try to center crossAxisaligment but don't know why its not working just showing in left side

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width:  width * 0.9,
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff1bb273)),
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff1bb273), width: 2.0),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff1bb273), width: 2.0),
                ),

                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xff1bb273)),
                ),
                //fillColor: Colors.green
              ),
              validator: (val) {
                if (val.length == 0) {
                  return "Email cannot be empty";
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xff1bb273)),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

As you can see i have wrap the container in Column. I just need to center it

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to set `crossAxisAlignment` for `Column`. Just wrap your `Container` with `Center`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your *Column* is getting left-aligned, and it is getting occupied with the child's (Container) width. *CrossAxisAlignment.center* makes, Column's children aligned to the center. But not the Column itself.

To make the *Column* widget to center you have to wrap it inside *Center* or *Align* widgets.

```
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
      ...
```

I guess you intend to add more fields to your column. So, by making changes to *alignment* parameter of **Align** and *crossAxisAlignment* parameter of **Column** widgets you can achieve your desired result.